# Batch rename long filenames of variable length with years

Tags: rename, batch-jobs

I have a bunch of files in a single directory that I would like to rename as follows, example existing names:

```
1937 - Snow White and the Seven Dwarves.avi
1940 - Pinocchio.avi
```

Target names:

```
Snow White and the Seven Dwarves (1937).avi
Pinocchio (1940).avi
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Perl based `rename` (sometimes known as `prename`) this is indeed possible. If you understand Regular Expresssions it's even straightforward.

```
rename -n 's!^(\d+) - (.*)\.(...)$!$2 ($1).$3!' *.avi
```

What this does is split the source filename into three components. Using your first example these would be

- 1937
- Snow White and the Seven Dwarves
- avi

These are assigned to `$1`, `$2`, `$3` within the `rename` command. (These are not `bash` variables.) It then puts them back together again in the different order.

When you are happy with the proposed result, change the `-n` to `-v`, or even remove it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I'd do it using bash only

```
cd movie_directory
ls -1 | while read line
do
  year=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $1}')
  name=$(echo ${line} | cut -d " " -f 3- | cut -d"." -f 1)
  ext=$(echo ${line} | cut -d " " -f 3- | cut -d"." -f 2)
  newname=${name}" ("${year}")."${ext}
  mv "${line}" "${newname}"
done
```

assumptions:

file names do not contain `.`
the space characters between the year and `-` and the file name are actually white spaces, not `tab` or some other unprintable character.

Comment: You might prefer `for line in *` rather than your `ls | while read...` construct